# internal:gem_prelude can't start the redmine update

Tags: ruby, redmine, centos6

When I do:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
```

or:

```
rails
```

or:

```
gem
```

The answer is:

```
<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

I don't know what to do, I did as most of topics says about completely deletion of ruby and a new installation, it didn't help.
CentOS 6 is installed and I'm trying to launch an update of redmine.

There is a tip about rvm command, but it didn't work at all, of any kind.

Comment: You should first type which ruby to figure out if you are using system's ruby or RVM's installed one. Then after that, perform re-installation via rvm, or installation and setup.